# Majorate semidefinite continuous matrix by a constant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A(x)=[a_{ij}(x)]_{i,j=1,\dots,n}$, $x\in {\bf R}^n$, be a symmetric  non-negative definite matrix:
$$
\langle A(x) \xi,\xi \rangle \geq 0 \ \ \forall x,\xi \in {\bf R}^n.
$$ Assume that
$$
a_{ij}\in C(K), \ \ K\subset {\bf R}^d,
$$ where $K$ is a compact set.

Let 
$$
a_{ij}^0=
\begin{cases}
\min\limits_{x\in K} a_{ij}(x), \ \ i\neq j\\
\max\limits_{x\in K} a_{ij}(x), \ \ i= j
\end{cases}
$$ Let 
$$
A^0=[a_{ij}^0]_{i,j=1,\dots,n}.
$$ I believe that it holds
$$
\langle A(x) \xi,\xi \rangle \leq n \langle A^0 \xi,\xi \rangle, \ \ \xi\in {\bf R}^n,
$$ but I cannot prove it. I am very grateful for any hint.

Comment: Do you assume the matrix $A$ to be symmetric? If $\sigma$ denotes symmetrization, one typically has $\sigma(A^0)\neq(\sigma A)^0$.

Comment: Yes, sure. I have forgotten that. Thanks a lot. So, I have forgotten to add the assumption that $A$ is symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false.  In particular, $A^0$ need not be positive semidefinite.  For example, take $n=3$, $K = \{1,2,3\}$, let $v(x)$ be the column vector with a $1$ at position $x$ and $-1$ elsewhere, and let $A(x)=v(x)v(x)^T$.  Then
\[
A^0 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 & -1 \\ -1 & -1 & 1\end{bmatrix},
\]
and the all ones vector is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-1$.